# Upgrading from Foundation 5.0.3 to 5.1.0 Breaks JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

I'm working on a Rails application which was using Foundation 5.0.3. This had a few issues with Rails 4, but I had it working with no issues. I am not using TurboLinks.

I've just updated to Foundation 5.1.0, and all Foundation JavaScript has stopped working. As far as I can tell, nothing else has changed, there are no resources returning 404, and there are no JavaScript errors coming out of the browser console.

I don't know if the problem is Foundation, the asset pipeline, or my project setup and page structure, but I've tried everything I can think of to debug this with no effect.

Here's my basic page structure in case the error is in how I've set it up, but this was working fine for Foundation 5.0.3.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <%= favicon_link_tag "favicon.png" %>
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all" %>
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag params[:controller] %>
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag "site_area_specific/#{params[:site_area]}" %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag params[:controller] %>
        <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $(document).foundation();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%= render "shared/topnav" %>
        <%= yield %>
        <%= render "shared/footer" %>
    </body>
</html>
```